# How to edit multiple row at a time using angular2 using form

Tags: angular, edit, onsubmit

want to edit multiple row at a time using angular2 form

edit btn not allwing to edit multiple rows at a time, while trying to open edit first row edit get closed and selected rows edit get open , but requirement is all row should be editable

Comment: Can you fill us in with more details and if possible the code where you are having trouble, so that we can help you in a much better way.

Answer (score 2):

You can add FormGroup field on your entity model.

For example;

```
export class Product{

   name:string
   manufacturer:string
   editForm:FormGroup
   isEditing:boolean
}
```

And in your table;

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Manufacturer</th>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let product of products">


        <ng-template [ngIf]="product.isEditing">

            <form [formGroup]="product.editForm">

                <td>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="name" />
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="manufacturer" />
                </td>

                <td>
                    <button type="submit" (click)="saveChanges()">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" (click)="product.isEditing = false">Cancel</button>
                </td>


            </form>


        </ng-template>


        <ng-template [ngIf]="!product.isEditing">

            <td>{{product.name}} </td>
            <td>{{product.Manufacturer}}</td>
            <td><button (click)="product.isEditing = true">Edit</button></td>

        </ng-template>


    </tr>
</tbody>
```

On save changes

```
saveChanges(product:Product){

//Maybe api call

product.isEditing = false

}
```

Answer (score 1):

on click of userEdit pass user object and assign it the the form u have as shown below. It will work. After editing now click on submit, it will reflect on all rows with in the form

```
userEdit(user) {
  this.form.setValue({
    username: user.username,
    email: user.email
  })
}
```